# How to access file from qt resource file on android?

Tags: android, c++, qt

how to access a xml file from the qt resource file on android device? Are there any special settings that need to be taken?

The Resource File:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
        <file alias="keyStorage">xml/key.xml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

The c++ code for call the file:

```
void MyClass::myfunction() {
    Q_INIT_RESOURCE(qml);

    QFile xmlFile("qrc:/xml/key.xml"); 
    //...
}
```

The QML code for call the file (main.qml):

```
ListView {
    width: 320
    height: 120
    model: listModel
    delegate: Text{ text: "key: " + key }
}

XmlListModel {
    id: listModel
    source: "qrc:/xml/key.xml"
    query: "/root/pair"
    XmlRole {
       name: "key"
       query: "key/string()"
    }
    onStatusChanged: {
        console.log(listModel.errorString())
    }
}
```

and last but not least the xml file (key.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<root>
    <pair>
        <key>0815</key>
    </pair>
    <pair>
        <key>1337</key>
    </pair>
</root>
```

I've tried as path:

- `:/xml/key.xml`
- `:/keyStorage/key.xml`
- `:/keyStorage`
- `qrc:/keyStorage/key.xml`
- `qrc:/xml/key.xml`
- `qrc:/keyStorage`

but nothing work.. The following errors was displayed:

- `qml: Error opening :/xml/key.xml: Unknown error (error from the XmlListModel)`
- `io\qiodevice.cpp:820 (qint64 QIODevice::read(char*, qint64)): QIODevice::read: device not open (error from c++)`

The resource file was added in the .pro file

**EDIT:**

Open a image from the resource file is possible only the xml file failes..

**EDIT_2:**

Hallo everybody,

I didn't find a solution for this problem, but I found that something goes wrong during adding an new directory to an existing project. When i added the xml file to an existing directory it works all fine. Adding a new directory didn't work..